# Google CSE does not find recent pages added to my website

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search

I added a Google CSE to my website, that searchs only in my website: `*.mywebsite.com/*`

I verified my website in Webmasters Tools
and after 3-4 hours the engine was able to find all the pages properly...

All this happened about 2 weeks ago.

---

Two days ago I added more 5 pages to my website, but today,
the engine still does not find the new pages...

What steps have I to follow, to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to resend the sitemap in webmaster tools, or add the new links in Google CSE control panel